# Remove auto generated id while using Firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following function:

```
 Future<void> addLoyalty(int points) async {
    print('inside add loyalty'); 
    final url =
        'https://fnj11223.firebaseio.com/loyalty/$userId.json?auth=$authToken';
    try {
        await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode({
          'points': points,
        }),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Here's the database snapshot:

[image]

I want to get rid of the extra ID generated. How can I tweak my function to achieve this?

Comment: Hello, any reason for not using the [official Flutter plugin](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/overview)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a `POST` request which is equivalent to the `push()` method in Firebase Client SDKs. If you want to write at a specific location without the push key, make a `PUT` request as mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-put).

Sample request from the docs:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{ "first": "Jack", "last": "Sparrow" }' \
  'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/users/jack/name.json'
```

Comment: put did it for me. Thanks alot.

Comment: but, when u used PUT. it can't add a new item. but, it makes updating the oldest data into the newest data and it makes me stuck if we found any case that needs to show all data lists without a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

Insert firebase real time plugin to your app `pubspec.yaml` file instead of calling APIs. As Plugin gives you advance feature and easy to integrate functionality
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database/install

Instead of adding just set values to your reference.

like `dbRef.set({your json goes here})`